# How to change a N/A value with another value in the same dataset

Tags: r, conditional-statements, na

I need help with N/A replacement.
I have a dataset with several NA value. I would replace them with the values that I find in the dataset.
I mean: the dataset is made by US States and some socioeconomics variables.
For the State South Dakota I have a N/A under the variable "non-citizens".
I would replace that N/A with the value of the variable "non-citizen" of the State Maryland.

Is it possible somehow? Can anyone help please?
Thank you

i find the conditional replacement but it didn't solve because instead of 1.32 i need to put another condition

data_num$non-citizen[is.na(data_num$non-citizen) & data$state=='South Dakota'] <- 1.32

EDIT - EXAMPLE

I decided to replace the NA with the values of the state that is more similar to it. I calculated the distances among the states with
function dist.
Then, for the states with NA value, checked the nearest state (so the state with the minimun distance).
For each state with NA, the aim is to replace the NA value of a variable with the value of that variable of the nearest state (so, if Arkansas is near Colorado, the NA under "income" of Arkansas would be replaced with "60940").

The best would be to develop a code that checks the distances from the matrix then assigns the NA value ... but i think that's too hard to implement!

[this is a part of the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmTlj.jpg)

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with `dput`.  Do you have the same number of observations for 'South Dakota' and 'Maryland'

Comment: 1) 1.32 is NA replacement, new Value if NA,  
2)the conditions in your code are ``is.na(data_num$non-citizen)`` AND ``data$state=='South Dakota'``

Comment: yes. But i would find a code like this: if (data$state=='South Dakota') & (data$non-citizen== NA),  then replace the NA with the value of (data$non-citizen & data&state=='Maryland')